# Error 1643 The file at 0x0025a48f could not be archived

Tags: macos, monterey

I recently upgraded to Monterey (on my 2015 MBP) and have been occasionally getting the following message popping up.

`Error 1643 The file at 0x0025a48f could not be archived`

I have tried to track down the app causing it but have been unsuccessful so far. It's honestly more of an irritant than anything as nothing seems to be obviously broken however still would be nice to fix. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? In the Terminal? In an alert dialog? Notification? Are you archiving anything? Mail? Have you verified the disk?

Comment: Yes it's a popup dialog that seems to randomly occur, its happened while web browsing or writing docs but nothing related to the message i.e. I'm wasn't archiving anything at the time. Good idea on verifying the disk thank you, haven't tried that yet, will give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently and it was an absolute nightmare to track down, firstly are you running CrashPlan Enterprise (I think can also be called Cloud or Small Business or something else along those lines)? If you are not then I'm afraid this is probably not the solution that you are looking for.

##### TLDR;

Run the following curl command on a machine in a known good state, compare it to yours and then make the required changes.

```
    curl --insecure -X GET "https://localhost:4244/v1/ApplicationStatus" -G -d 'query=list+config+where+version=v6.9.4'
```

### Background

Firstly a bit of background, CrashPlan is essentially made of two components, a Service and a UI. The UI is built using the Electron framework, I believe this used to be a Java app (and you can tell the age of your install by this). The service is pretty much what does all of the work, and it hosts an API (on a webserver) that is listening port `4244`. We can talk to this API to find out what is going and to try to work out what is *broken*. If you are interested in looking at what API routes are available (and what calls get made etc) you can look into the UI's App.asar file (its all of the *compressed* JS that make up an Electron app), reading that is how I worked all of this. What appears to happen is during the upgrade very occasionally some configuration gets corrupted or deleted, really not sure why (I wasn't able to find a root cause for that).

### How to solve

#### Step 1

We need to check the configuration from a machine (in your company) that you know is working, that way you can diff the two configs and work out what is missing on the machine that is broken.

We need to query the runtime configuration from the known good host. Use the following `curl` command to send a request to the internal API to retrieve the runtime configuration. This uses the internal endpoint `v1/ApplicationStatus` to query the config that is currently being used. It will be returned in `JSON` and you can use `jq` to format it nicely if you so desire.

```
    curl --insecure -X GET "https://localhost:4244/v1/ApplicationStatus" -G -d 'query=list+config+where+version=v6.9.4'
```

#### Step 2

Run the above curl command on the host where you are getting the error message. Hopefully this should return a config that it different to the one above, or if you are lucky it will point you the config that is either missing or is incorrect.

### Step 3

Add whatever is missing (or needs to be removed) from the runtime configuration to the configuration file `/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan/conf/my.service.xml`

#### Step 4

Reboot the machine and problem should go away

Hope that helps

Comment: We’ve used this product at work  in several forms for 6 years and I’ve never once seen this message. This is amazing detective work and reverse engineering! Thank you so much for the lessons here.

Comment: Wow that is an incredible effort, thank you for taking the time to write all that down. I never would have found that!!